# JSON Object in Object refer in HHML

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, ngfor

i have a JSON-datafile of typ: trip. In trip is a object: driver (with name, id etc..).

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "gpsStart": "N50.418716° , E006.750000°",
  "gpsEnd": "N50.318516° , E006.750000°",
  "tripBuinsness": true,
  "startOdometer": 25698,
  "endOdometer": 25700,
  "wayPoints": [
    "N50.418716° , E006.750000°",

  ],
  "driver": [{
    "name": "Theo"
  }]
}
```

How can I refer the driver name in html?

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let trip of trips">
    <td>{{trip.projectName}}</td>
    <td>{{trip.driver}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: `driver` is an array. You will need to use `ngFor` for it same way like you have used for `trips`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need **`ngFor`** over trip since its an Object, change it over **`trip.driver`** which is an array of Objects,

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let driver of trip.driver">
  <td>{{driver.name}}</td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the only the first driver you can access him through the 0th index:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let trip of trips">
    <td>{{trip.projectName}}</td>
    <td>{{trip.driver[0].name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

But if you want all of the drivers add another ngFor loop to your template:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let trip of trips">
    <td>{{trip.projectName}}</td>
    <td>
      <span *ngFor="let d of trip.driver">{{d.name}} </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

'driver' is an array. I think you can access the name by doing trip.driver[0].name or iterating over trip.driver.